# Programmatically retrieving the current playing song, album and artist from Spotify

Tags: windows, spotify

With Spotify's most recent update, the old method to retrieving the current playing song, album and artist is not usable anymore. The old method looked at all open window titles until it finds one with "Spotify - SONG...", and then it removed "Spotify - " resulting in "SONG...".

The newest Spotify only has "Spotify Premium" in its title, and my old method is doomed...

That's why I'm looking for an alternative method, but so far, I haven't been able to find an alternative.

Someone told me to look inside the "C:\Users\NAME\AppData\Roaming" folder and look for Spotify's stream output from one of the files in there. I couldn't find anything close to resembling a "stream output" however...